# не могу составить оптимальный маршрут LATITUDE LONGITUDE

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas, fastapi

@router.post("/")
async def create_new_route(file: UploadFile = File(...), session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
contents = await file.read()
reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(contents.decode('utf-8')))

```
async with session.begin():
    route = Route()
    session.add(route)
    await session.flush() 
    points = []
    for row in reader:
        lat = float(row['lat'])
        lng = float(row['lng'])
        points.append(Point(lat=lat, lng=lng, route_id=route.id))

    session.add_all(points)
    await session.commit()
    
query = select(Route).options(joinedload(Route.points)).where(Route.id == route.id)
result = await session.execute(query)
route = result.scalars().first()
route_data = {"id": route.id, "points": [{"lat": point.lat, "lng": point.lng} for point in route.points]}
return route_data
```

этот код просто записывает из файла lat lng
мне нужно точек нужно составить оптимальный маршрут и записать потом вернуть его в return
или с начало записать потом построить оптимальный маршрут и вернуть его

Comment: Я что-то не могу уловить суть проблемы, тут помимо знаков препинания ещё и слова потерялись?! Можете как-то переоформить свой... текст?